# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Form Dropdown with Bootstrap

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

All of the fields I've added in the form are getting the value except the drop down button with bootstrap.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" name="gender" onclick="getGender()">
        <span id="selection">Select Gender</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" th:field="*{gender}">
        <a class="dropdown-item" th:value="'Male'">Male</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" th:value="'Female'">Female</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I searched but only to find this https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-select-option the difference is it is using **select** tag and my code is not. So it is not working properly. **What are the possible options to get the Gender?**

Here is the error:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Dec 18 17:54:06 CST 2019 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). PreparedStatementCallback;
>   SQL [INSERT INTO tblusers(username, password, fullname, email, gender)
>   VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; ERROR: null value in column "gender" violates
>   not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains (11, jckuuuu0009,
>   hahahehe, Jack The Ripper, jck@gmail.com, null, 0).; nested exception
>   is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column
>   "gender" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains
>   (11, jckuuuu0009, hahahehe, Jack The Ripper, jck@gmail.com, null, 0).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to `insert` a row where `gender` is null into your `tblusers` `table`, while that's not allowed. You will need to specify a valid value for `gender`, which exists in the referenced `table`.

Comment: Yes. But the problem is the code not the way the insertion of the data into the table. It doesn't get the value Male or Female when I'm selecting the drop down into the variable Gender.